# angular2 simulate rest service

Tags: rest, angular

First of all I want to emphasize I am an Angular2 newbie (or even less...). The backend REST services are not ready yet so I should simulate them somehow.

I checked on the net how it can be achieved and I found the following ways:

- using a JSON server
- using the MockBackend
- mocking the service itself

I am just wondering if there is a magical 4th way where I have to do minimal configuration and coding (yeah, I know the options above are not complex but I am a newbie so EVERYTHING is complex to me at the moment) and it works ?

Thanks,
V.

Comment: Maybe you could write which level you want to mock. Because if writing a service returning mock data is acceptable for you, I don't think there can be an easier option.

Comment: what about to import/read JSON from file, then later add service layer and remove these imports?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api

Comment: Thanks peeskillet! This in-memory-web-api looks promising! I will give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

The options which you mentioned are the easiest ones. May be have a look at the links which i have shared below. You will get more ideas to process with.

http://restlet.com/company/blog/2016/04/08/interacting-efficiently-with-a-restful-service-with-angular2-and-rxjs-part-1/

https://www.sitepoint.com/angular-2-mockbackend/

Comment: Hi yuvil_10, thanks for the response! I will try  in-memory-web-api that peeskillet recommended.